# create hibernate query to perform sum of two select query columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two select statements which calculates the sum of a column each .Need to fetch the sum of the two select statements . Its working in normal sql but not working on @Query annotation of hibernate.

Tried running the above problem using normal sql query its working but the same is not working on hibernate @Query annotation

```sql
select sum((SELECT   SUM(TRAN_AMT+FEE_AMT)
            FROM pymt 
            WHERE TRANTM between '2019-06-01 00:00:00' and  '2019-06-23 23:59:59'
            AND PAYEE = unhex('xxxxxx')
            AND TRANTYPECDE = '003' 
            AND RESP_CDE = 'Success')-(

SELECT   SUM(TRAN_AMT-FEE_AMT)
            FROM pymt
            WHERE TRAN_CAPTR_DT_TM between '2019-06-01 00:00:00' and  '2019-06-23 23:59:59'
            AND PAYEE = unhex('xxxxxx')
            AND TRANTYPECDE != '003' 
            AND RESP_CDE = 'Success')) as sumValue;
```

above is working but the below query in hibernate not working

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT SUM((SELECT   SUM(p.feeAmt + p.tranAmt) "
                    +"FROM PymtEntity p " 
                    + "WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to "
                    +"AND p.tranTypeCde = '003' " 
                    + "AND p.payeeId = :md "
                    + "AND p.respCde = :re )"
                    +"-"
                    +"(SELECT   SUM( p.tranAmt - p.feeAmt) "
                    +"FROM PymtEntity p " 
                    + "WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to "
                    +"AND p.tranTypeCde != '003' " 
                    + "AND p.payeeId = :md "
                    + "AND p.respCde = :re )) as sumtotal")
```

above return QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree

expect the sum to be printed 
but getting QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree in hibernate

Stacktrace

```
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT SUM((SELECT   SUM(p.feeAmt + p.tranAmt) FROM com.hsbc.digital.peak.payments.reporting.data.entities.PymtEntity  p WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to AND p.tranTypeCde = '003' AND p.payeeId = :merchantId AND p.respCde = :respCode )-(SELECT   SUM( p.tranAmt - p.feeAmt) FROM com.hsbc.digital.peak.payments.reporting.data.entities.PymtEntity  p WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to AND p.tranTypeCde != '003' AND p.payeeId = :merchantId AND p.respCde = :respCode )) as sumtotal]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT SUM((SELECT   SUM(p.feeAmt + p.tranAmt) FROM com.hsbc.digital.peak.payments.reporting.data.entities.PymtEntity  p WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to AND p.tranTypeCde = '003' AND p.payeeId = :merchantId AND p.respCde = :respCode )-(SELECT   SUM( p.tranAmt - p.feeAmt) FROM com.hsbc.digital.peak.payments.reporting.data.entities.PymtEntity  p WHERE p.tranCaptrTm >= :from AND p.tranCaptrTm <= :to AND p.tranTypeCde != '003' AND p.payeeId = :merchantId AND p.respCde = :respCode )) as sumtotal]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why don't you make a single query for the sum without all the subqueries? I strongly believe that is possible

Comment: since i have  diffeerent where condition i need go for a two select query . Thing is with one select query @Query annotation is working

Comment: With the query you posted, its 2 times exactly the same query. Looks like you are missing a `!` in the second `AND p.payeeId = :md`. Also post the whole stacktrace

Comment: edited the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm biased since I develop it, yet this can be solved with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) since it feeds native SQL to Hibernate:

```java
@Entity
@Data // lombok
public static class PymtEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private int feeAmt;
    private int tranAmt;
    private Timestamp tranCaptrTm;
    private String tranTypeCde;
    private int payeeId;
    private String respCde;
}

public int sumTwoColumns(Date from,
                         Date to,
                         int md,
                         String re) {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL(() -> {
        PymtEntity common = subQuery((PymtEntity pymt) -> {
            SELECT(pymt);
            FROM(pymt);
            WHERE(BETWEEN(pymt.getTranCaptrTm(), from, to) && pymt.getPayeeId() == md
                                                           && pymt.getRespCde() == re);
        });

        PymtEntity first = subQuery(() -> {
            SELECT(common);
            FROM(common);
            WHERE(common.getTranTypeCde() == "003");
        });

        PymtEntity second = subQuery(() -> {
            SELECT(common);
            FROM(common);
            WHERE(common.getTranTypeCde() != "003");
        });

        SELECT(SUM(pick(first, SUM(first.getFeeAmt() + first.getTranAmt()))
                - pick(second, SUM(second.getTranAmt() - second.getFeeAmt()))));
    });

    return query.createQuery(em, Integer.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

And the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT SUM(((SELECT SUM((q3.fee_amt + q3.tran_amt)) 
FROM (SELECT q2.* 
FROM (SELECT t0.* 
FROM PymtEntity t0 
WHERE ((t0.tran_captr_tm BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ) AND ((t0.payee_id = ?3) AND (t0.resp_cde = ?4))) ) q2 
WHERE (q2.tran_type_cde = '003') ) q3 ) - (SELECT SUM((q4.tran_amt - q4.fee_amt)) 
FROM (SELECT q2.* 
FROM (SELECT t0.* 
FROM PymtEntity t0 
WHERE ((t0.tran_captr_tm BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ) AND ((t0.payee_id = ?3) AND (t0.resp_cde = ?4))) ) q2 
WHERE (q2.tran_type_cde <> '003') ) q4 )))
```